# PHP $_SESSION maxlifetime not working properly

Tags: php

For all pages in my website, I have this session check in the top:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{ 
    session_start();
}
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
?>
```

I use this to check if a user is logged inn. If the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to login page.

In the very top of the login.php page, I have this:

```
<?php

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 8 hours
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 28800);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 8 hour
session_set_cookie_params(28800);

// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Basically this should make the session last for 8 hours, yes?

When the user successfully logged in, I get the SESSION: `$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;`

What am I doing wrong here? Why does my users keep getting logged out/redirected to login page after being inactive for a while, when I set the SESSION to last for 28800 seconds = 8 hours?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221663/discussion-on-question-by-cfwef12-php-session-maxlifetime-not-working-properly).

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is set once initially when there is no session cookie present in the client request. That means: the settings are only applied once initially, **not** every time you hit `session_start()`.

When you start the session, the cookie time starts to expire, not when you login actually.

So if you visit the site early and start an 8 hour session, but you login 7,5 hours later, your "login" will expire in 30 minutes (8 hours - 7.5 hours = 0.5 hour).

Technically, your problem is here:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{ 
    session_start();
}
```

The session starts without a specific expiration time.
But you want to explicitly specify an expiration time when the session starts:

```
<?php
// Put this on top of ALL pages that RELY on session
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 28800);
    session_set_cookie_params(28800);
    if (!session_start()) {
        throw new \Exception('Failed to start a new session');
    }
}
```

When someone logs in successfully you do like:

```
<?php
if (login_successful()) {
    // Beware of race conditions in flakey wifi or with concurrent requests
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['someToken'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
```

Setting an expiration time later has no effect because cookies do not get "refreshed" without changin values (or session id).

There are two more problems with your code:

1. Without `session_regenerate_id()`, you are vulnerable to session fixation https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation
2. You do not have authentication implemented at all. Everybody can "login" to your site by simply creating a local cookie with `loggedin=true`. No password or username are checked.

Comment: They are already doing that, with `session_set_cookie_params(28800);`

Comment: As @CBroe said. I have already done that in the second line: `session_set_cookie_params(28800);`.

Comment: And what you are saying regarding the TTL, isn’t exactly true either. When you log in, new data will be written into the session, so the file modification timestamp will be updated, and that is what the garbage collector bases its decision on, which files to clean up. And the lifetime of the cookie gets updated with every call to `session_start`.

Comment: @CBroe My second paragraph is regarding the TTL of the session cookie on the client, not the timestamp of the session data on the server.

Comment: So what, that still doesn’t make sense. _“and you log in 7.30 hours later”_ - then `session_start` will be called again at _that_ point, so a new cookie with a lifetime of 8 hours will be set at _that_ point.

Comment: @CBroe thats exactly the point which is not true: A session cookie is present, it will not set a new cookie automatically with fresh 8 hours ttl, it will reuse the cookie which has been set in the past. Edit: I just verified this - no new cookie. If you want a fresh cookie, you need to use `session_regenerate_id()` or fully destroy and restart a session.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I was under the impression that session_start would send a new cookie header every time it gets called. But calling session_regenerate_id should be able to fix that, and calling that when a critical step like login is performed, is a good idea anyway.